# Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3c6e918c

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

While Running a tomcat server with multiple application in webapps folder. One application is shutting down while rest are working perfectly fine.

My Console output for the application shutting down is

```
2020-02-24 14:34:41.319  INFO 20872 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2020-02-24 14:34:41.373  INFO 20872 --- [           main] tpa.ap.fcn.FCNWebApplication             : Started FCNWebApplication in 21.968 seconds (JVM running for 190.2)
2020-02-24 14:34:41.624  INFO 20872 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
24-Feb-2020 14:34:43.560 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
24-Feb-2020 14:34:43.560 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/tpa-ap-fcn-web] startup failed due to previous errors
2020-02-24 14:34:43.572  INFO 20872 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3c6e918c: startup date [Mon Feb 24 14:34:21 IST 2020]; root of context hierarchy
2020-02-24 14:34:43.574  INFO 20872 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2020-02-24 14:34:43.575  INFO 20872 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'aps'
24-Feb-2020 14:34:43.667 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [tpa-ap-fcn-web] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@438baad]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl@6d08cc5c]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

My Pom.xml

```
<!-- SPRINGBOOT CONVERSION Dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

has all required dependency

Comment: please provide log for failed application context

Comment: @MeetPatel This is the details coming in my log rest all the log files of catalina and localhost are empty. Is there anyplace other than log folder in tomcat where we can get the logs for application context

Comment: Log line `24-Feb-2020 14:34:43.560 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file`
Seems like filters are failing to start. Do you have any servlet filters or any Spring security configurations in application?

Comment: Thanks @NeeteshBhardwaj .... I was working on Springboot security with version 2.5 and it has a dependency freemaker inbuilt but I was externally defining it also in pom.xml with different version so it was automatically closing the application and filter was failing to start

Answer (score 0):

`AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext` is replaced by `AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext` in the `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context` package in Spring boot 2.x versions.